# Why is the output true for given statement in ruby?

Tags: ruby, output

I called the following statements on a range `triples = "AAA".."ZZZ"`:

1. `triples.include? "ABC" # => true: slow in ruby 1.9 and fast in ruby 1.8`

   I understood why the output is `true`, but couldn't get why it's fast in ruby 1.8 and slow in ruby 1.9.
2. `triples.include? "ABCD" # => false: ruby 1.9  and true: ruby 1.8`

   I couldn't get why the output is different in both versions.
3. `triples.cover?   "ABCD" # => true and fast in ruby 1.9`

   The same problem as the second statement.

Why are `cover?` and `include?` statements different in ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby >= 1.9, `include?` iterates through every element in the range and checks to see if the given element is present.

`cover?` just checks whether the element is >= the first element range and <= the last element of the range.

Because of the way Ruby sorts strings (lexically),
`"ABCD" > "AAA"` and `"ABCD" < "ZZZ"`.

In Ruby 1.8, `include?` is treated like Ruby 1.9's `cover?`.

To answer your question of why they are different, your example illustrates the need for the two different methods well.

For example, if you want to check if a number is in a numeric range, `(0..1_000_000_000).cover?(1_000_000_001)` is much faster than `include?` -- checking two elements instead of a billion.

However, your example shows why `include?` is necessary: `"ABCD"` is not actually included in the range `("AAA".."ZZZ")`, but it is covered by it.

Comment: Ok . but what about the speed of execution that is being said about ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9 in statemenets 1 and 3?

Comment: @KavishDwivedi because the 1.9 `include?` has to iterate through all of the elements of the range (there are 26^3 of them). `cover?` just checks the first and last elements.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.9 or above, for non-numeric ranges, `include?` returns true only if the parameter is a member of the range.

I'd like to add that for numeric ranges, `include?` is still the same as `cover?`:

```
r = 1..10
r.include?(5) # => true
r.include?(5.5) # => true
```

> [Range#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F)
>
> Returns `true` if `obj` is an element of the range, `false` otherwise. If `begin` and `end` are numeric, comparison is done according to the magnitude of the values.